# How to convert a parsed text into a plain text

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, text-processing

I have parsed a text and extracted all noun-phrases using Stanford parser. Now I need to convert my parsed noun phrases into the plain text:

Input:

```
(NP (DT the) (JJ dallas) (NN country) (NN club))
(NP (NP (CD 25) (NN cent)) (NP (NNP bingo)))
```

Expecting Output:

```
the dallas country club
Cd 25 cent bingo
```

Note: I can clean the text in an ugly way that includes lots of "replace" methods. However, I prefer cleaning it in a more professional way or by using a tool embedded in Stanford parser API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't speak for the Stanford API, but this can be (fairly) easily accomplished with a regular expression, such as the following:

```
(?<=\([A-Z]+ )[^\(\)]+
```

So what does this do?

- First, we want to make sure that the text we actually want to match against is preceded by an open parentheses, followed by some number of capital letters, and then a space.  For this, we use a lookbehind.  For example, `(?<=foo)bar` will match the "bar" in "foobar", but not in "ackbar" or just "bar".  In our case, we populate the lookbehind with an escaped open parentheses `\(`, followed by at least one `+` capital letter `[A-Z]`, then a single space character .
- Matching the subsequent text itself could be tricky, because (in theory - again, I don't know how Stanford's parser handles things) phrases could consist of more than one word, or it could be hyphenated or otherwise strangely punctuated, etc.  So we take advantage of the anti-selector, `^`, which matches everything EXCEPT what is noted within its selector.  For example, `[^ABC]` would match all characters EXCEPT capital A, B, and C.  So we simply match at least one `+` character that is not a closing parentheses `\)`, which will match all characters until we hit the closing parentheses.
- A small bug introduced in the above bullet is that this does not account for nested phrases.  Matching simply against the closing parentheses will match the `(NP (CD 25` in `(NP (NP (CD 25))`, which is obviously not what we want.  So we also disallow matching against the opening parentheses `\(` to account for this.

All well and good... except Java makes things more difficult than they need to be.

- First, Java's lookbehind parser doesn't like lookbehinds of unknown possible length, for some reason.  So we have to change the `+` in `[A-Z]+` to use a length range, e.g. `[A-Z]{2,3}`, which will match strings of capital letters 2-3 characters long.  **Note that if the Stanford parser denotes phrases with keys that have more or fewer capital letters than you have noted here, you will have to adjust that range accordingly!**
- Next, Java regexes must be compiled before use.  Part of said compliation is turning escaped characters into character literals.  But that will turn `\(` and its counterpart into literal opening and closing parentheses, which the regex engine will then treat as regex parentheses, which will cause it to fail.  So the escaped backslashes themselves must be escaped before compilation, turning each `\` into a `\\`.

So our final regex reads:

```
(?<=\\([A-Z]{2,3} )[^\\(\\)]+
```

Then it can be fed into Java in some manner like this...

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

...

public ArrayList<String> GetMatchesFromNLP(String text) {
  ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
  Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\([A-Z]{2,3} )[^\\(\\)]+").matcher(text);
  while (m.find()) {
    matches.add(m.group());
  }
}
```

...which will add each regex match into a new element of an ArrayList.

For performance purposes, you may wish to turn that ArrayList into a linked list of some sort, depending on how long your input text is.

Comment: Thanks to @Diosjenin: This response is very comprehensive and great. It works very well. The only required edit is that in the parser we have (NP (PRP$ our)(NN economy) so this solution will remove (PRP$ our) that is incorrect. By removing all $ signs this approach works accurately.

Comment: @user3147590, since that's the case: Rather than remove $s before executing, you can add an escaped $ `\\$` and mark it optional `?` after the capital letter match.  The new regex will read `(?<=\\([A-Z]{2,3}\\$? )[^\\(\\)]+`, which will match the "our" in "(PRP$ our)".

Answer (score 2):

The output format is determined by the `formatString` passed to Stanford Parser's `TreePrint` constructor.

The one you're getting is the "oneline" option:

```
(NP (DT the) (JJ dallas) (NN country) (NN club))
(NP (NP (CD 25) (NN cent)) (NP (NNP bingo)))
```

The one you want is "words":

```
the dallas country club
25 cent bingo
```

According to the [TreePrint javadoc](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/TreePrint.html), known formats are:

```
oneline, penn, latexTree, xmlTree, words, wordsAndTags, rootSymbolOnly,
dependencies, typedDependencies, typedDependenciesCollapsed, collocations,
semanticGraph, conllStyleDependencies, conll2007
```

This example from the [Stanford Parser homepage](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) shows how to set this on the command line using the `-outputFormat` flag:

> ```
> java -mx200m edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser
> -retainTMPSubcategories -outputFormat "wordsAndTags,penn,typedDependencies"
> englishPCFG.ser.gz mumbai.txt
> ```

Comment: I'm using constituency parser

Comment: I would have to see your code in order to show you where the output format needs to be set. The Stanford parser specifically supports your desired output format. You just need to know where to set it.